# how to reload a div after ajax callback without a specific class in that div

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, reload

is it possible to reload a div after an ajax call without a specific class inside that div?
I have a div with class `comments` which i want to reload after an ajax call.
The classes `media` and `modal` are generated by a foreach loop.

```
<div class="comments">

    <div class="media">
       some content here
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
       content of modal
    </div>

    <div class="media">
       some content here
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
       content of modal
    </div>

    <div class="media">
       some content here
    </div>
    <div class="modal">
       content of modal
    </div>

</div>
```

My ajax:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);        
    $(".comments").load(" .comments > *"); // reload div comments 

},
```

So i am looking for something like:

```
$(".comments").load(" .comments > *"); // reload div comments except the classes .modal in that div
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the modal classes while updating comments?

Comment: yes the media classes should be updated but not the modal classes

Comment: `load()` will replace everything in the target. To keep some elements you could save a reference to them in a variable, detach them, load the content, then re-attach the elements again in the callback. Alternatively you could run the function which generates the content again in the callback, although these will be brand new elements, not the originals should that be important for your logic. Alternatively you could amend the server response to include everything, or just return JSON and build the HTML structure manually. Personally, I'd amend the logic to use one of the last two methods.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-refresh-a-DIV-without-reloading-the-whole-page
or i just copy this

```
 $("#divToReload_WithDAta").load(location.href + " #divToReload_WithDAta");
```